# Unable to Perform Maven Release

Tags: git, maven, version-control, maven-release-plugin

I am trying to Preform a Maven Release using Jenkins. But I am having some issues.  This is my first time doing a Maven Release. Jenkins pulls down my code from the Git repository and changes all the pom files to the correct Version. I can see this my examining the Jenkins workspace. however it does not seem to be pushing the changes back up to the Git repo with the version changed. Git uses a code review tool call Gerrit that I should have to approve once it preforms the mvn release.

I have set SCM in my main POM
    `<scm><developerConnection>scm:git:ssh://<user>@<IP_Address>:<Port>/<Repo_Name>.git</developerConnection></scm>`

I am getting a error

Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.0:prepare (default-cli) on project <Name>: An error is occurred in the checkin process: Exception while executing SCM command.
cause : An error is occurred in the checkin process: Exception while executing SCM command.
Stack trace : .....

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you something more detailed to show ? You can create a Gist or pastebin to give us more context.

Comment: does this help http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Hr4meuUk

Comment: Do you still have the same problem? I have the same problem and I would like to know how to fix

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the pastebin.

The error `Caused by: org.apache.maven.scm.ScmException: Detecting the current branch failed: fatal: ref HEAD is not a symbolic ref` can often be tricked by setting `Checkout/merge to local branch (optional)` to `master` (if you're releasing `master`) in section `Advanced...` of Git parameter.

Comment: How do I tell it to create a new branch and push up to Gerrit and the Git repo?

Comment: Maven release:prepare and release:perform will only modify the branch you're currently releasing. If you want to create a new branch, you may add a build step `Execute shell` with few git commands (`git checkout -b new-branch old-branch; git push gerrit new-branch;...`)